# Give an example of a sequence of n integers withΩ(n 2 ) inversions

Tags: algorithm, runtime, complexity-theory

I'm working on a exercise but it's confusing to understand.

I assume that the worst case for a inversion is that there is a sequence that's sorted in descending order: [n,n-1,...,0] which has (n(n-1))/2 inversions. Then we have to prove that (n(n-1))/2 >= C · n^2 based on the definition of omega which is g(n) >= C · f(n). But when n goes to infinity, g(n) = 1/2, so there doesn't exist a constant C which C>=1 and n0 >= 1 that satisfy the inequality.

What am I missing?

Comment: The definition of Omega is that C>0, not C>=1. That is, f(n)=Omega(g(n)) if there's n0 and C>0 such that for all n>=n0, f(n) >= Cg(n).

Comment: For example, n(n-1)/2 >= n^2/4 for all n>1.

Comment: You don't have to assume that sorted descending is the worst case.  You merely have to show that the number of inversions cannot exceed the number of pairs of integers.

Comment: @PaulHankin sorry for the late reply, C can be fraction as well?

Comment: @btilly I couldn't wrap my head around this question. How come showing that the number of inversions always <= number of pairs of integers proves that a sequence has $omega$(n^2) inversions?

Comment: @AlexHu Ah, it is looking for an example, not an upper bound.  Sorry, ignore my previous comment.  As for your other question, C can be any positive real number.  Including fractions.

Comment: @btilly huh thank you, also I wanna ask how do I literally understand this question, is it asking for a sequence which has n integer and with at least n^2 inversions?

Comment: @AlexHu yes, C can be any positive real number. The requirement of C should be part of the definition you're using, and if you're not using a definition then you should start by finding one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the question you are asked is, *Give an example of a sequence of `n` integers with `Ω(n^2)` inversions.*

They worded this a bit sloppily.  But here is what you need to come up with:

1. The rule for generating sequences.
2. A number `0 < n_0`.
3. A constant `0 < C` such that if `n_0 < n` then the number of inversions of the `n`th sequence is greater than `C * n^2`.

You've already given a rule that you think might work. `n` numbers sorted descending.

I would suggest that you try `n_0 = 2` and `C = 1/4`.

Can you prove this statement?

*If `2 < n`, the descending sequence of length `n` has more than `(1/4) * n^2` inversions.*